# Apache beam windowing weird behaviour

Tags: python, apache-beam, windowing

I have developed a sample beam pipeline in Python, that receives some data from a pubsub subscription (the data element is the name of a person with it's age, the objective is to count how many persons over certain age are inside a fixedwindow).

The FixedWindow is set to 30 seconds, without additional configuration.

The issue is that the output is triggered randomly, after the first output the pipeline starts emitting output data (like 5 or 6 outputs) between the current window and the next one that should emit a result after 60 seconds.

```
    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    data = p | ReadFromPubSub(topic=known_args.input, with_attributes=True, timestamp_attribute="timestamp")
    transformed = (data                                                              
                   | 'FormatMessage' >> beam.Map(format_message)                                              
                   | 'Add Timestamp: %s' >> beam.ParDo(AddTimestampDoFn())
                   | beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(30))
                   | "Filter" >> beam.Filter(filter_names, known_args.rules)
                   | "ReMap" >> beam.Map(lambda x: (x['data']))                                                                  
                   | beam.ParDo(CollectTimings())                  
                   | 'Group' >> beam.GroupByKey()
                   | 'Count' >> beam.CombineValues(beam.combiners.CountCombineFn())
                   )        

    serialized = (transformed
                  | beam.Map(lambda x: json.dumps(x))
                  | beam.Map(printresults)
                 )

    serialized | "Write To PubSub" >> WriteStringsToPubSub(known_args.output)
```

From what I understand, based on Beam documentation, I should be receiving outputs (if there is at least one input data) every 30 seconds, but I'm getting an multiple outputs inside the window.

What can be the cause of this behaviour?

Comment: Beam's windowing behavior is by default going to depend on event time rather than processing time, so you may well see outputs at some interval other than 30 seconds of wall clock time. In your example, you're telling ReadFromPubSub to assign the "timestamp" attribute as the event time for each Pub/Sub message. When you start up the pipeline, there will likely be some backlog of messages to read, so I'd expect windows to close faster than real time until it gets caught up. Could that explain the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: To add Jeff's point, you are using default trigger (the mechanism that controls when a window emits result.). The default trigger means it triggers when watermark passes the end of window. Given this context, fixed 30 sec windowing does not guarantee every 30 seconds. It really depends on how your source's watermark move. Say if your watermark halts at a specific timestamp, then you will not see any results emitted.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your answers, what I'm specifically seeing right now as you say is that when the inputs are being processed the outputs are coming out at different times. I tried running the same code directly on dataflow, and what happens is that the output is not sent until I stop the data generator, but since the timestamp is assigned the the PubSub topic I don't understand why is this happening.